# TinyMCE WordPress 4.9.6 Issues with TinyMCE.ui.Controller

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

When the page loads running TincyMCE.ui it only loads Factory methods to use and TinyMCE.ui.Controller is undefined. Any ideas on what would cause this error?

Edit: this is an issue that is new with 4.9.6, 4.9.5 loads the TinyMCE.ui.Controller

edit: https://i.gyazo.com/6d1d648183acdd3c3207ceb1bf95d883.png Added an image to show the issue